# How can I copy dependencies from a library project to the main project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dllimport, setdlldirectory

I have an Asp.Net project (Vb.Net) that references a managed dll (library written in C#). That library project has several unmanaged dependencies dlls in a lib folder (copied into bin/Release/lib folder during build). The library is not a part of the main solution.

My library uses [DllImport] that references an unmanaged dll. But to let the unmanaged dll be found, I call SetDllDirectory():

```
        string path = // don't know how to generate the path
        SetDllDirectory(path);
```

I am struggling with generating the path to the unmanaged dll and its dependencies. I can start with my main project bin folder or something. But what should I do next? E.g. is there a way to copy the unmanaged dlls from the library's bin/Release/lib folder to my main project's bin folder? Or some other solution?

Comment: How about adding `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)lib\*.*" "$(OutDir)..\" /y /e` to the post build events?

Comment: @Asti Thank you for your suggestion. May I ask how I can set OutDir to point to my main project's bin folder?

Comment: It's a macro which is automatically set by the build path.

Comment: @Asti I used xcopy "$(ProjectDir)lib\*.*" "$(TargetDir)" /y   , it seems to be what I need. If you would like to make your suggestion an answer, I would mark it as such. Thanks!  I will not even need to use SetDllDirectory(), as I am making my library a NuGet package, so upon installation, all dlls will be copied right to the bin folder.

Comment: Hey, glad it worked out. I've added it as proper answer in case it might be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this:

1. Add the Dlls to the VS project as a file, then set `Build Action` to `None` and `Copy to output directory` as `Copy`. This should ensure that any external dependencies of the referenced library are copied.
2. Add a command like `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)lib\*.*" "$(OutDir)\" /y /e` or `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)lib\*.*" "$(TargetDir)" /y` to the Build Events section in Project properties. This should copy the *\lib* directory from the project root to the output.